# Create the same set with different name in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to create multiple equal sets with different names.I tried something like that:

```
model.j=model.i
```

something that i have seen on the Pyomo documentation in the operations chapter (4.2) but when i run the program i get the following error :

```
RuntimeError: Attempting to re-assign the component 'i' to the same
block under a different name (j).

This behavior is not supported by Pyomo; components must have a
single owning block (or model), and a component may not appear
multiple times in a block.  If you want to re-name or move this
component, use the block del_component() and add_component() methods.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to initialize one Set with another

```
model.j = Set(initialize=model.i)
```